Why is Abraham referred to by his new name but not Jacob; whose name was changed to Israel?
All references are from the King James Version.
In Genesis 17:5 Yahweh changes Abram to be called Abraham-the father of a multitude of nations. We refer to him as Abraham to this day.
In Genesis 17:15, Sarai's name is changed to Sarah; no problem.. Readers refer to her as Sarah today.
In Genesis 32:28 AND in Genesis 35:10, we're told that Jacob is not to be called Jacob any more; but he is to be called Israel. From there, his name is consistently referred to when mentioned with the Patriarchs as "The God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob" which should read "The God of Abraham, Isaac and Israel" anywhere this string of Patriarchs is mentioned. I have found one instance of it in 1st Kings 18:36-39 which includes "Israel" as one of the Patriarchs.

If Abraham is addressed by the name God changed it to, why isn't Jacob's name replaced with the name God changed it to; which is Israel? We refer to Saul as Paul, and his name was never actually changed. What's the deal?


It is worth to note that the term "Israel" carries two distinct meanings. Here's a rough estimate of its usage in each context;

Jacob; The term "Israel" refers to Jacob approximately 10 times (e.g. Genesis 32:28; 35:10)
The Nation: it is used hundreds of times in the OT to refer to the nation of Israel

When referring to individual, as in "The God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob", the term "Jacob" is used to avoid confusion with the nation. However, while the Lord is indeed "The God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob", He is also the God of the nation of Israel. In such contexts, the term "Israel" is used to describe God's relationship with the nation.

As far as I understand, Israel referring to the nation implies all the descendants of Jacob, but not all the descendants of Abraham or Isaac (like Ishmael and Esau.)

The facts are not as clear as the OP understands them to be. It is true that the formula "Abraham, Isaac and Jacob" became standard. However, there are 198 references to the "God of Israel" in the Hebrew Bible. The phrase "God of Jacob" is used only 18 times. Thus, the question might also be asked this way: why is God referred to as the God of Israel so frequently, rather than being called the God of Jacob?
As to why "Abraham, Isaac and Jacob" became the norm, the name "Israel" has a somewhat unfortunate history. It was the name given to the northern Israelite kingdom, as opposed to the more godly kingdom of Judah. This association may have been a factor in the biblical writers tending to refer to the patriarch as "Jacob" rather than "Israel." [The following is not relevant to those who reject the documentary hypothesis, but source critics also point to the fact that name Israel came from the "E" source while Jacob's name originate with "J" source (southern).]
Conclusion: "God of Israel" is actually used more often in the Bible than "God of Jacob." However, the formula "Abraham, Isaac and Jacob" is indeed standard. This probably has to do with Israel's association with the north, whose tradition is generally denigrated in the biblical narrative.

That's a decent effort but a little hard to follow for me. I would emphasize "became standard" and toss it up to the pen of the scribes; authors in this case. Through the modern lens, I could see why one would not want to associate the covenant name in Yahweh with a covenant people; called by His name. Nonetheless, thanks for the effort.

The reason for the selection of one name over the other is a different theological message that a particular biblical author was trying to put through. That one is obvious. The problem is that we often don't get it and don't follow the original train of thought. Although I am unable to explain to you all the reasons behind the text, I can share with you what I know.
The names of the three patriarchs hide the basic message of salvation.
Abram (the exalted father) represents God the Father. When his name is changed to Abraham (the father of many nations), paradoxically, he has only one son. Ishmael represents here the physical nation of Israel. That is what Paul tells us in his Letter to Galatians 4:

21 Tell me, you who want to be under the law, are you not aware of
what the law says? 22 For it is written that Abraham had two sons, one
by the slave woman and the other by the free woman. 23 His son by the
slave woman was born according to the flesh, but his son by the free
woman was born as the result of a divine promise. 24 These things are
being taken figuratively: The women represent two covenants. One
covenant is from Mount Sinai and bears children who are to be slaves:
This is Hagar. 25 Now Hagar stands for Mount Sinai in Arabia and
corresponds to the present city of Jerusalem, because she is in
slavery with her children. 26 But the Jerusalem that is above is free,
and she is our mother.

Through Isaac, the son of the promise, who represents the Christ, God did become the father of many nations. Jacob represents the believers, the elected ones of God. The change of heart and transformation from Jacob (the deceiver) to Israel (He Retains God/He Has Become A Receptacle In Which God Can Be Received And Retained) is a picture of the work of the Spirit of God in His people. That spiritual Israel, the royal priesthood of God, is called to be an intermediary between unbelieving humanity, whose picture was Esau, and God.
God remains the father of the nations forever, once He reestablished His fatherhood through Christ, the new Adam (representative of humanity). Hence, only the name of Abraham is used. It is a little bit different for us. We still experience some ups and downs, living life spiritually parallel to the conquest of Canaan by Joshua Ben Nun (Jesus the son of the fish). The struggle between the flesh and the spirit is our every-day experience. The reality of that spiritual battle is described even by our Savior in Luke 21:19:

By your patience possess your souls.

The interchangeable use of the names Jacob and Israel may be a picture of the constant clash of the physical with the spiritual. Something we know from our own lives and experience daily.
As for Paul of Tarsus, he never stopped being Saul. Since the creation of the diaspora, the Jews have often used two sets of names.

“ A large number of English-speaking Jews have observed and still
observe the custom of giving their children both Hebrew and English
first names—the former for religious purposes, the latter for everyday
life. Although Jewish law does not insist on Hebrew names for such
rituals as being called up to the Torah, or for circumcision, wedding,
and funeral ceremonies, their use on these occasions is customary. ...
Such double naming, one name drawn from Jewish tradition and the other
from the surrounding non-Jewish culture, is an ancient Jewish
practice. We first encounter it among the Hasmonean dynasty that ruled
in Palestine, a country whose economic and social elite spoke Greek,
prior to its becoming a Roman province in the early 1st century CE.“
https://mosaicmagazine.com/observation/religion-holidays/2022/06/the-history-of-jews-giving-their-children-both-hebrew-and-english-first-names/

The apostle never stopped being Saul. Since Paul was appointed as the messenger for the nations, he was using his Greek name while living among the gentiles.

When you say "That spiritual Israel, the royal priesthood of God, is called to be an intermediary between unbelieving humanity, whose picture was Esau, and God"; are you suggesting that the original seed of Jacob/Israel-the Israelites referred to as a remnant no longer exist? Zeph. 2:7, Romans 9:27, 11:5 and Revelation 7:4-8; 11:13 and 12:17, would disagree with that hypothesis.

The physical is always a picture of the spiritual. The temple, the sacrifices, the circumcision... and the ethnic nation of Israel. The descendants of Abraham that believe are part of the Israel of God. The unbelieving ones are going to be regrafted as Romans 11 tells us.

For I could wish myself to be a curse, separated from Christ for my brothers, my kinsmen according to the flesh, (Romans9:3)

1Further, my brothers and sisters, rejoice in the Lord! It is no trouble for me to write the same things to you again, and it is a safeguard for you. 2Watch out for those dogs, those evildoers, those mutilators of the flesh. 3For it is we who are the circumcision, we who serve God by his Spirit, who boast in Christ Jesus, and who put no confidence in the flesh— 4though I myself have reasons for such confidence.(Philippians 3)
